# Increase size of symbols in the matplotlib legend?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I draw a plot with markers like so:

```
plt.scatter(xs1, ys1, s=12, linewidths=0, marker='o', label='hello')
plt.scatter(xs2, ys2, s=12, linewidths=0, marker='x', label='hello')
```

this produces the right size in the graph, but the symbols are hardly intelligible in the legend. How can I increase the size of the symbols *in the legend*?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the solution in [matplotlib.pyplot.legend](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html). The legend takes an attribue 'markerscale'.

```
plt.legend(loc='best',markerscale=2)
```